# Как удвоить символ построчно в тексте через функцию?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции

Уже не первый день пытаюсь выполнить задание, ничего не выходит. То съедает символы, если разные индексы, то не удваивает с одинаковыми индексами. Я уже не знаю решения, всяко пробывал.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <clocale>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

void udv(char* mas, char* mass, char sym, int i, int &k)
{
   int d;
   do
   {
     k++;
     *(mass + k) = *(mas + k);
     if (*(mas + k) == sym)
       {
         d = k;
         *(mass + (d++)) = sym;
       }
   } while (i >= k);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
   const int m = 100; int k = 0;
   char sym; int i=0; int peer=0; char sym2;
   char* text=new char[m];
   char* stroka=new char[m];
   for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
     {
       *(text+i)=0;
       *(stroka+i)=0;
     }
   cout<<"Введите символ, который будем удваивать: ";
   cin>>sym;
   cout<<sym<<endl;
   cout<<"Введите символ переноса строки: ";
   cin>>sym2;
   cout<<sym2<<endl;
   cout<<"Введите произвольный текст (использовать символ переноса строки): "<<endl;
   cin.get(text, m,'*');
   cout<<"Введенный текст:\n";
   cout<<text<<endl;
   cout<<"Символов переноса: "<<endl;
   while (*(text+i))
   {
     i++;
     if(*(text+i)==sym2)
        peer++;
   }
   cout<<peer<<endl;
   for (int i=0; i<'0'; i++)
     {
        if(*(text+i)==sym2)
        {
           udv(text, stroka, sym, i, k);
           cout << k << i;
           cout << "Новый текст ";
           for (int i = 0; i < '0'; i++)
              cout << *(stroka+i);
          cout << endl;
        }
     }
 cout << "Готовый массив:";
 for (int i = 0; i < '0'; i++)
    cout << *(stroka + i);
 delete[] text;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: А покороче можно? В две строки: что на входе и что должно получиться на выходе.

Comment: Если пишете на C++, то и делайте как положено, через `std::string`. Ваш код должен быть каким-то таким: `string result; for (char c : source) { ... result += c; ... }`. Не нужно пытаться изменить строку на том же месте, просто составьте новую.

Comment: @VladD
Это задание и, к сожалению, я не могу использовать другие библиотеки.

Comment: "*Это задание*" - какое задание? Вы нормально его сформулировать можете, или надеетесь на наши телепатические способности? А `std::string` - это не "другая", а  **стандартная**, то бишь родная библиотека для C++. Тем более что `cout` и `cin` вы используете, так вот это то же самое.

Comment: @UliyanRomanov: Строка в C++ — это именно `std::string`. Настоящая, правильная, единственная существующая в языке. То, что вы используете как строку (`char*`) — это строка языка C. Они разные.

Comment: @klopp 
Задание от преподавателя в универе. Знаю, что родная библиотека, но я не могу перечить преподу и делать как мне хочется, он сказал в массиве работать, значит я так должен, увы. Я лишь надеюсь, что вы можете исправить кусок кода. На входе - одномерный массив, состоящий из строк в которых есть несколько одинаковых символов, например "\".  На выходе - тоже самое, только с удвоенным "\".

Comment: @UliyanRomanov: Я бы посоветовал делать в два прохода. Первый проход подсчитывает, сколько раз встречается символ, и тем самым вы узнаете длину выходного массива. Затем заводите выходной массив, и точно так же проходитесь по исходному массиву, копируя символы в выходной массив и при необходимости удваивая их. Таким образом необходимость в перемещении данных отпадает.

Comment: @VladD
Я так делал и меня послали переделывать. Потому что нужно обрабатывать массив со строками **построчно**. Что я и сделал в этом примере. Я каждую строчку отправляю в функцию, там пытаюсь удвоить (что пока не получается), заношу в новый массив и вывожу результат. Результат плохой. Тот же текст, только либо без удовенного символа, либо с удвоенным, который лишь закрывает следующий символ. Причем индекс я увеличиваю!

Comment: @VladD
Другой вариант удвоения, который как рак таки закрывает следующий символ, стоящий впереди.
`void udv(char* mas, char* mass, char sym, int i, int &k)
{
 for (k; k <= i; k++)
 {
  *(mass + k) = *(mas + k);
  if (*(mass + k) == sym)
  {
   k++;
   *(mass + k) = sym;
  }
 } 
}`

Comment: @UliyanRomanov, см. продолжение ответа.

Comment: И последняя часть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, раз с третьей попытки с заданием определились, начнём с самого начала.

Первое. Вы совершаете типичную ошибку: вместо того, чтобы сосредоточиться на *решении отдельных задач*, начинаете лепить груду кода, который делает *сразу всё*, начиная с никому не нужного (на этом этапе) ввода данных. Это только мешает и запутывает. Давайте попробуем как-то организовать процесс.

Подзадача 1: удвоить определённые символы в строке. Пишем шаблон-заглушку, пытаясь понять что на входе и что на выходе, и работаем только с ним:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char * dup_chars( const char * src, char ch )
{
    // пока тут пусто
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char * result = dup_chars( "abcabcabc", 'a' );
    printf( "%s\n", result );
    // уже понятно, что результирующая строка будет длинней,
    // и память для неё будет выделяться внутри dup_chars(),
    // поэтому освобождаем:
    free( result );
    return 0; // C++ пока тут и не пахнет
}
```

**Всё, больше ничего нам не нужно**. Вот с этим шаблоном и начинаем думать дальше.

```
static char * dup_chars( const char * src, char ch )
{
    // определяем длину исходной строки:
    size_t src_len = strlen( src );
    // понятно, что нам нужна будет как минимум длина исходной строки 
    size_t desr_len = src_len; 
    char * dest = malloc( dest_len + 1 );
    return dest;
}
```

Думаем дальше:

```
static char * dup_chars( const char * src, char ch )
{
    size_t src_len = strlen( src );
    size_t dest_len = src_len; 
    // считаем символы, которые удваиваются:
    for( size_t i = 0; i < src_len; i++ )
    {
        if( src[i] == ch ) dest_len++;
    }
    // вот теперь мы точно знаем длину новой строки
    char * dest = malloc( dest_len + 1 );
    return dest;
}
```

И последний шаг, собственно удвоение в уже подготовленную строку:

```
static char * dup_chars( const char * src, char ch )
{
    size_t src_len = strlen( src );
    size_t dest_len = src_len; 
    for( size_t i = 0; i < src_len; i++ )
    {
        if( src[i] == ch ) dest_len++;
    }
    char * dest = malloc( dest_len + 1 );
    // будем использовать эту переменную как текущий индекс в строке-результате:
    dest_len = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < src_len; i++ )
    {
        // копируем символ исходной строки
        dest[dest_len] = src[i];
        dest_len++;
        // он "наш"? копируем ещё раз:
        if( src[i] == ch ) 
        {
            dest[dest_len] = ch;
            dest_len++;
        }
    }
    // и не забываем последний 0:
    dest[dest_len] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

**Всё!**

Вот теперь точно так же, *разбивая на кусочки*, попробуйте решить следующую задачу: выделение подстрок из одной исходной строки по символу-разделителю. И когда это будет сделано, можно будет объединять решения, наворачивать ввод внешних данных и прочее, прочее, прочее... Даже - *заниматься оптимизацией* :) **Но только после того, как все подзадачи будут решены,  отлажены и протестированы отдельно!**

---

**Продолжим**. Пока всё равно не понимаю что значит "построчно" (а выше что, поквадратно?). Но попробуем к этому подобраться, исходя из вашего кода. Допустим, какой-то злодей запретил пользоваться динамическим выделением памяти. Значит, функция `dup_chars()` должна принимать на входе место для результата и размер этого места. OK:

```
static char * dup_chars( const char * src, char * dest, size_t dest_len, char ch )
{
    size_t dest_pos = 0;
    size_t src_pos = 0;
    while( dest_pos < dest_len && src[src_pos] )
    {
        dest[dest_pos] = src[src_pos];
        dest_pos++;
        if( dest_pos >= dest_len )
        {
        // Не хватило места! Хорошо бы вывести ошибку и/или вернуть,
        // NULL. А лучше - сначала подсчитать сколько понадобится
        // и если больше, чем dest_len, то вообще не портить
        // строку результата. Но пока в это не будем упираться.
            break;
        }
        if( src[src_pos] == ch )
        {
            dest[dest_pos] = ch;
            dest_pos++;
        }
        src_pos++;
    }
    dest[dest_pos] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Проверяем:

```
int main()
{
    char src[] = "abcabcabc";
    char dest[32];

    printf( "%s\n", dup_chars( src, dest, sizeof(dest), 'a' ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Вроде всё нормально. Сейчас (**и только сейчас, не раньше**) переключаемся на вторую задачу: разбить входную строку на подстроки и передать их в функцию `dup_chars()`. Стандартными средствами C это делается так (допустим, разделителем у нас будет символ `0`):

```
int main()
{
    char src[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char dest[32];
    char * ptr = strtok( src, "0" );
    while( ptr )
    {
        // тут у нас в ptr находится готовая C-строка,
        // если нужно где-то её сохранить, то самое время
        // это сделать
        printf( "%s\n", dup_chars( ptr, dest, sizeof(dest), 'a' ) );
        ptr = strtok( NULL, "0" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но опять пришёл какой-то редиска и запретил нам пользоваться функциями стандартной библиотеки. Или мы не хотим модифицировать входную строку (что делает функция `strtok()`, её описание смотрите в справочнике по стандартной библиотеке C). Значит, нам нужно передавать в `dup_chars()` не "обычную" C-строку, а указатель на первый символ нужной подстроки и её длину. OK, меняем всего чуть-чуть:

```
static char * dup_chars( const char * src, size_t src_len,
                         char * dest, size_t dest_len, char ch )
{
    size_t dest_pos = 0;
    size_t src_pos = 0;
    while( dest_pos < dest_len && src_pos < src_len )
    {
        dest[dest_pos] = src[src_pos];
        dest_pos++;

        if( dest_pos >= dest_len ) break;

        if( src[src_pos] == ch )
        {
            dest[dest_pos] = ch;
            dest_pos++;
        }
        src_pos++;
    }
    dest[dest_pos] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Теперь ищем во входной строке символы-разделители и передаём в `dup_chars()` найденные фрагменты. И вынесем символы (разделитель подстрок и что удваивать) в отдельные переменные. А чтобы было "совсем похоже" (ну, вдруг это не заметно), обзовём все переменные так же, как у вас (хоть это и неправильно - давать такие имена):

```
int main()
{
    char text[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char stroka[32];
    char sym = 'a';
    char sym2 = '0';

    char * ptr = text;
    char * end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    while( end )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", dup_chars( ptr, end-ptr, stroka, sizeof(stroka), sym ) );
        // пропускаем все разделители, ведь их
        // может быть больше одного подряд:
        while( *end == sym2 ) end++;
        ptr = end;
        end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    }
    // и захватываем "хвостик" входной строки, если он остался:
    if( *ptr )
        printf( "%s\n", dup_chars( ptr, strlen(ptr), stroka, sizeof(stroka), sym ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Ну вот вроде и всё. Я так и не понял, что значит "построчно", но вроде бы вариантов развится событий у нас уже накопилось достаточно.

Так что теперь можно заняться и остальными вещами: вводом символа-разделителя, вводом символа для удвоения, вводом исходной строки, обработкой ошибок (помните про превышение длины результата?), *накоплением подстрок исходной строки и строк-результатов в массивах (материала для этого мы уже собрали достаточно, каким путём больше нравится, тем и можно пойти)*, оптимизацией и прочей рутиной.

---

**И последняя часть**. Теперь мы захотели сохранять и подстроки входной строки, и строки с удвоением. Для этого нужны два массива строк. Поскольку C++ мы не хотим, то память для них придётся выделять вручную. Сколько? Мы не знаем, сколько в результате получится строк, и какова будет длина каждой из них. Но не беда. Для начала - ещё раз *забудем про этот идиотский подход: решать все проблемы сразу*! Попробуем посчитать сколько всего будет строк, используя один из подходов, описанных выше (именно этот чтобы не портить входную строку, она нам ещё пригодится):

```
int main()
{
    char text[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char sym2 = '0';
    size_t data_len = 0;

    char * ptr = text;
    char * end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    while( end )
    {
        data_len++;
        while( *end == sym2 ) end++;
        ptr = end;
        end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    }
    if( *ptr ) data_len++;
    printf( "%u\n", data_len );
    return 0;
}
```

Получилось вывести `3`? Отлично! Значит, можно выделять память:

```
int main()
{
    char text[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char sym2 = '0';
    size_t data_len = 0;

    char ** strings_in; 
    char ** strings_out; 

    char * ptr = text;
    char * end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    while( end )
    {
        data_len++;
        while( *end == sym2 ) end++;
        ptr = end;
        end = strchr( ptr, sym2 );
    }
    if( *ptr ) data_len++;

    strings_in = calloc( data_len, sizeof(char *) );
    // на выходе столько же строк, сколько на входе:
    strings_out = calloc( data_len, sizeof(char *) );

    // и подчищаем за собой:
    for( size_t i = 0; i < data_len; i++ )
    {
         free( strings_in[i] );
         free( strings_out[i] );
    }
    free( strings_in );
    free( strings_out );

    return 0;
}
```

Зачем я написал вроде бы бессмысленную пустышку,  которая ничего не делает? Затем, что её нужно обязательно собрать, и прогнать, чтобы убедиться - память мы уже на этом этапе распределили правильно, правильно освобождаем, нигде ничего у нас не "течёт", память не запарывается, и т.д. В идеале уже этот код (как и любой другой, впрочем) нужно прогнать через [valgrind](http://alexott.net/ru/linux/valgrind/Valgrind.html) или через его [аналоги под Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/).

Теперь в этот шаблон нужно вставить заполнение `strings_in` и `strngs_out` данными. И снова *мы не будем решать обе задачи одновременно*! Сначала заполним только входной массив:

```
int main()
{
    size_t i; 
    char text[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char sym2[2] = { '0', 0 };
    size_t data_len = 0;
    char ** strings_in;
    char * ptr = text;

    // обратите внимание: здесь мы уже скомбинируем
    // оба варианта прохода по строке, поэтому и чуть
    // изменили представление sym2.
    char * end = strchr( ptr, sym2[0] );
    while( end )
    {
        data_len++;
        while( *end == sym2[0] ) end++;
        ptr = end;
        end = strchr( ptr, sym2[0] );
    }
    if( *ptr ) data_len++;

    strings_in = calloc( data_len, sizeof(char *) );

    // делаем второй проход и копируем строки
    // в i - текущий индекс strings_in
    i = 0;
    ptr = strtok( text, sym2 );
    while( ptr )
    {
        strings_in[i] = strdup( ptr );
        i++;
        ptr = strtok( NULL, sym2 );
    }

    // выводим строки и сразу освобождаем память:
    for( i = 0; i < data_len; i++ )
    {
         if( strings_in[i] )
         {
             printf( "%s\n", strings_in[i] );
             free( strings_in[i] );
         }
    }
    free( strings_in );
    return 0;
}
```

Получилось вывести ровно те строки, что и ожидали? OK, дальше на очереди засовывание в `strings_out` результата. Вот тут-то нам и пригодится самый первый вариант, с динамическим выделением памяти под него! Возвращаемся к самому началу, смотрим на прототип самого первого варианта `dup_chars()` и пишем **окончательный вариант**:

```
int main()
{
    size_t i;
    char text[] = "abc0abc0abc";
    char sym2[2] = { '0', 0 };
    char sym = 'a';
    size_t data_len = 0;
    char ** strings_in;
    char ** strings_out;
    char * ptr = text;

    char * end = strchr( ptr, sym2[0] );
    while( end )
    {
        data_len++;
        while( *end == sym2[0] ) end++;
        ptr = end;
        end = strchr( ptr, sym2[0] );
    }
    if( *ptr ) data_len++;

    strings_in = calloc( data_len, sizeof(char *) );
    strings_out = calloc( data_len, sizeof(char *) );

    i = 0;
    // не хотите strtok()? не беда, чуть-чуть измените это
    // место (как? подумав головой!)
    ptr = strtok( text, sym2 );
    while( ptr )
    {
        strings_in[i] = strdup( ptr );
        i++;
        ptr = strtok( NULL, sym2 );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < data_len; i++ )
    {
        strings_out[i] = dup_chars( strings_in[i], sym );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < data_len; i++ )
    {
         if( strings_in[i] )
         {
             printf( "Source: %s\n", strings_in[i] );
             printf( "Result: %s\n", strings_out[i] );
             free( strings_in[i] );
             free( strings_out[i] );
         }
    }
    free( strings_in );
    free( strings_out );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хороший tutorial!

Comment: Ого! Теперь это уже учебник.