# Удаление строчки из файла С

Tags: c

Здравствуйте столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Нужно удалить строчку из файла. Строчку в начале которой содержится определенное название вводимое с клавиатуры
Есть файл user.txt
В нем записаны логины и пароли пользователей вот в таком виде

```
user    250cf8b51c773f3f8dc8b4be867a9a02
```

Нужно сделать так что бы если пользователь ввел с клавиатуры слово user то удалилась вся строчка в начале которой написанно user
Вот сам код который есть на данный момент который выводит все содержание файла, предлагает выбрать имя для удаления.

```
void userDELL()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char log1[100], pass1[100], log_f1[100], pass_f1[100], log_f2[100], pass_f2[100];
    text = fopen("user.txt", "r");
    printf("\n       Список зарегистрированных пользователей           \n");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n   ЛОГИН              ||  ПАРОЛЬ\n\n");
    while (fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1) == 2)
    {
        printf("   %-18s || %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
    }
    printf("\nВведите логин пользователя которого вы хотите удалить: ");
    scanf_s("%s", log_f2);
}
```

Comment: так в чём вопрос?

Comment: Так вы тут даже попытки удаления не делаете, что конкретно от нас хотите? И - стандартная ошибка: вы вывалили кучу кода, которая никакого отношения к вашему вопросу и вашей задаче не имеет. Зачем? Решайте задачи по отдельности,  попытки нагородить код, который делает сразу всё, ни к чему хорошему не приводят. Попробуйте почитать мои разглагольствования на эту тему здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428344/

Comment: Имеется файл в котором записаны данные. Пример я показал выше как записаны данные. Нужно в нем удалить стройку в которой содержится в начале определенное слово

Answer (score 2):

Стандартная ошибка: попытка написать код, который делает сразу всё. Не нужно так делать. Ваша задача - удалить строку из файла? Тогда выкиньте всё, что к этому не относится, и займитесь только этой задачей. Вот когда она будет решена, тогда и можно переходить к другим, к объединению с остальным кодом и тд.

```
static int remove_line( const char * filename, const char * start )
{
  /*
    А тут, в комментариях, попробуйте изложить алгоритм удаления
    строки. Нормальными, человеческими словами.
  */
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
   remove_line( "test.txt", "user" );
   return 0;
}
```

Начинаем:

```
static int remove_line( const char * filename, const char * start )
{
  /*
     Удалить что-то из файла можно так:
      1. прочитать строку
      2. если её нужно оставить - записать её во временный файл
      3. если пропустить - ничего не делать
      4. GOTO 1 пока есть строки
      5. переименовать временный файл в наш
     Я исхожу из того, что строк, подходящих под критерий,
     может быть несколько. Если только одна, то алгоритм тот же.
     Если несколько, но удалять надо только первую, то алгоритм
     чуть меняется, как - самостоятельно, pls.
  */
  return 0;
}
```

Во, теперь понятней, приступим к реализации:

```
static int remove_line( const char * filename, const char * start )
{
  /*
     Ошибки проверять пока не будем, имя временного
     файла правильно создавать - тоже. Потому что это 
     другие задачи, а мы сейчас решаем одну-единственную.        
  */
  FILE * infile = fopen( filename, "r" );
  FILE * outfile = fopen( "/tmp/test.tmp", "w" );

  /*
     Теперь нужно построчно читать входной файл. 
     Проверять строки на соответствие их начала
     строке start. Если оно - пропускаем, если нет -
     записываем во временный.
  */
  fclose( infile );
  fclose( outfile );
  /*
     Ну и в конце - переименовываем временный файл в filename.
     Пока этого не делаем, ибо - другая задача.
  */
  return 0;
}
```

Этого пока достаточно. Когда комментарии в последней болванке будут заменены реальным кодом, когда этот код будет отлажен (с помощью отладчика и `main()` из одной строчки!), вот тогда можно будет решать другие подзадачи. А это как минимум:

1. обработка ошибок и возврат соответствующего кода (пока у нас 0 в любом случае)
2. правильное создание временного файла
3. корректное переименование

И вот когда и это будет работать как часы (в той же `main()` из одной строчки), вот тогда и можно будет переходить к интеграции с другими функциями программы.